# Hanoi Tower amount of combination?

Tags: c++, algorithm, towers-of-hanoi

Recently i was on an interview for C++ Develpoer position, and i was asked to write a program that solve a hanoi tower puzzle with 3 columns and 1000000 discs, the program must write an output of moves to disk("1->3","1->2",... and so on), i told them that this will be a very big file for solution, because minimum amount of moves for hanoi tower is 2 power n - 1 and for 1000000 this will be very big number that not fit to any hard drive, they say that classical algorithm is wrong and there is an algorithm wich solve this puzzle even for 1000000 discs with fever moves. I want to know is there exist such an algorithn or they just lie to me?

Thanks, Timur.

Comment: They are probably looking for proof that optimal solution for Tower of Hanoi problem is 2^n - 1 when the number of pegs is 3.

Comment: they may just have tried to intimidate you, some human resource people are just... nasty.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2650/how-to-prove-the-optimal-towers-of-hanoi-strategy

Comment: Maybe if you have a fancy file system that allows referencing the same block several times from the same file...

Answer (score 0):

The output would indeed be too big (exponential in the size of the input as you said), but the algorithm is fairly simple to write in a recursive manner. Perhaps that's what they meant.

I could provide the algorithm if you want.

EDIT: Just for the sake of completness I'd provide the algorithm (its in Python, but implementation in C++ will be pretty much the same):

```
n = 3
# using 4 elements just so we're 1-based with three towers
towers = [ [], range(n, 0, -1), [], [] ]

def move (orig, dest, n):
    if n == 1:
        elem = towers[orig].pop()
        print 'moving %d from %d to %d' % (elem, orig, dest)
        towers[dest].append(elem)
    else: 
        through = dest ^ orig
        move(orig, through, n-1)
        move(orig, dest, 1)
        move(through, dest, n-1)

move(1, 3, n)
```

Comment: The recursive solution is going to blow the stack in C++ (and C and Java), unless the program is rewritten with external stack.

Comment: Classical algorithm is recursive, my program is using only one array with containing appropriate number of column for each disc, for million disc this will be 1 million char bytes array. They say that it is possible to write the 1000000 disc puzzle answers to hard drive. I think that they wrong, because as i sad earlier this will be 2 power n -1 moves, so this is imposible only if there is less moves algorithm wich i think is not exist.

Comment: @nhahtdh recursive solution would not blow stack, deepness of recursion is linear on problem size. http://ideone.com/w7LTo0

Comment: @TimurKukharskiy, you are slightly wrong since to store values between 0 and 1000 you'll need at least a short (two bytes, since 1 byte isn't enough), and that will lead to roughly 2KB of storage for *the application* itself. Writing the solution (sequence of moves) will not be possible as you have mentioned, since there are not enough atoms in the universe for that.

Comment: And -- @EvgenyPanasyuk is right; the maximal *depth* of the recursion is indeed bound by n and therefore not an issue.

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk: `deepness of recursion is linear on problem size` Then the stack will have 1 mil stack frames. Assuming only 8 bytes per frame (return address and previous frame pointer, we will ignore the parameters for now), you will need 8 MB of stack space.

Comment: @nhahtdh do you think that 8MB of stack is too much? my program runs into error due to ideone time limit, as can be seen several moves are done, i.e. maximal recursion depth is reached

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk: 8M is assuming there is no parameters. You program is currently running on only 100K (Linux gives bigger stack than Windows - on Windows, 100K already enough to blow the stack). It dies with 1 million. http://ideone.com/dU7soN

Comment: @nhahtdh 1e6*4pointers*8bytes = 30.52MiB - it is not a big issue. You can try run 1M on your machine. moves are too long, ideone has limit only for 15s.

Comment: @nhahtdh yes - I didn't noticed your link, right stack size should be set (for instance at linker) - I tried set 100MiB stack at MSVC - and runs OK for 1M items.

Comment: As i said earlier my program is not using recursion so stack is not a problem, it used a unique algoritm wich i developed and it possible to solve up to any size wich is bordered by maximum size of one dimmensional array of chars which now is 1000000 this is only 1 Mb of memory for million of discs. I can post the solution.

Comment: @TimurKukharskiy: Can you post your code? (Since I am curious how you know what move to take next).

Comment: Here you go but it`s not so simple to understand:

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that i promised for  nhahtdh.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
char disc[2000000]={0};
int n;
bool validate(int num,int target){
    int t=num+1;
    while(t<n){
        if ((disc[num]==disc[t])||(disc[t]==target))return false;
        t++;
    };
    return true;
};  
int main()
{
    __int64 k=0;
    cout<<"Enter number of discs:";cin>>n;
    cout<<"This would be a "<<setprecision(1000)<<pow(2,n)-1<<" combinations !"<<endl;
    cout<<"To START press a key!"<<endl;
    _getch();
    int num=0,cur=0,t=0,nn=0;
    while(num<n){
        t=2;nn=num;
        while(nn<n){
            if(disc[nn]==t){nn++;continue;}
            if(validate(nn,t)){
                if(nn==num)num++;
                k++;cout<<disc[nn]+1<<"->"<<t+1<<":"<<k<<" move"<<endl;
                disc[nn]=t;
                nn++;
                continue;
            }
            if((disc[nn]==0)&&(t==2)){nn++;t=1;continue;}
            if((disc[nn]==0)&&(t==1)){nn++;t=2;continue;}
            if((disc[nn]==1)&&(t==2)){nn++;t=0;continue;}
            if((disc[nn]==1)&&(t==0)){nn++;t=2;continue;}
            if((disc[nn]==2)&&(t==1)){nn++;t=0;continue;}
            if((disc[nn]==2)&&(t==0)){nn++;t=1;continue;}
        };
    };
    return 0;
}
```

I hope you can understand but if not write me an e-mail to atlantic-sys@mail.ru i can explain more in details.